# Sort of columns in tabpage

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

How can I add sort of columns in ASPxPageControl? My code is below;

```
 <dx:ASPxPageControl ID="DataLookupTabs" runat="server" Width="100%"
      CssClass="dxtcFixed dxtcAligned horizontal-center-aligned" TabAlign="Justify" TabPosition="Top" ActiveTabIndex="0" EnableTabScrolling="true" ContentStyle-BackColor="Transparent" ActivateTabPageAction="Click" EnableHotTrack="True" AutoPostBack="false" EnableCallBacks="false" OnTabClick="DataLookupTabs_TabClick">
        <TabPages>
        </TabPages>
</dx:ASPxPageControl>
```

I added grid to Tabpages like that.

```
        for( int i = 0; i < userSession.MiscDataSet.Tables.Count; i++ )
        {
            page = new TabPage();
            page.Text = LocalizationHelper.GetGroupGlobalResourceString( "Tables", userSession.MiscDataSet.Tables[i].TableName + "Label", userSession.MiscDataSet.Tables[i].TableName );

            ASPxGridView grid = new ASPxGridView();
            grid.ID = userSession.MiscDataSet.Tables[i].TableName + "_grid";
            //grid.KeyFieldName = "GROUPCODE";
            grid.DataSource = userSession.MiscDataSet.Tables[i];
            grid.SettingsPager.Mode = GridViewPagerMode.ShowAllRecords;
            grid.Settings.VerticalScrollBarMode = ScrollBarMode.Visible;
            grid.Settings.VerticalScrollableHeight = 450;
            grid.Settings.HorizontalScrollBarMode = ScrollBarMode.Visible;
            grid.Width = Unit.Percentage( 100 );
            grid.CssClass = "mainDataDetailFormLayout";
            grid.Styles.Header.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            grid.SettingsBehavior.AllowSort = true;
            grid.DataBind();
            page.Controls.Add( grid );
            DataLookupTabs.TabPages.Add( page );
        }
```

And now I want to sort by the Column I clicked in the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you call the `DataBind` method, ASPxGridView should populate its columns. Access the required column via the [DataColumns](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.DataColumns) collection and apply sorting to the column using the [GridViewDataColumn.SortOrder](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataColumn.SortOrder) property.

```
grid.DataBind();
grid.DataColumns["Column2"].SortOrder = ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
```

If you need to apply sorting to all columns, you can do this in a [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays) loop.

```
grid.DataBind();
foreach (var col in grid.DataColumns) {
    col.SortOrder = ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
}
```

Comment: The column name is not fixed. It should be able to sort for all come columns, not for Column2.

Comment: You can use a ForEach loop for this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It worked, thanks! When clicked column header, I want to change sort type, how can I do that? Asc -> Desc or Desc -> Asc.